# Increase size of menu and add image?

Tags: android, layout, menu

The following activity in my app is the menu that links to the rest of the activities:

```
/**
 * Class containg avtivity that sets up a menu
 *  which then opens other classes 
 * @author Ross
 *
 */
public class Menu extends ListActivity{

    //array that holds the list of names of what will be displayed on screen in menu
    String classes[] = { "ViewTimesTables", "Practice", "RandomTest","About"
             };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //takes list or array adapter
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));

    }


    /**
     * Method that allows a class to be opened through the menu, dependent on what is clicked
     */
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        //**ADD COMMENT**
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        //Setting string equal to whatever position in the classes array
        String className= classes[position];

        try {
            //Allows class to be opened dependent on what is clicked
            Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.multapply." + className);
            // set up new intent based off class variable
            Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
            //Start the Activity
            startActivity(ourIntent);
        }

        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            //log error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The following is how the screen currently looks:

[image: Menu]

I would like to:

-Slightly increase the size of each menu item
-Have an alternating colour scheme, i.e. one green then white, rather than grey
-add an image under the menu (just for asthetics).
Note: This activity is not linked to an xml file. This is why im finding these changes difficult.

Comment: This activity is not linked to an xml file?

Comment: it needs to be if you want to customize it

Comment: So how would I create an xml file in order to link to the list view/adapter etc?

Comment: dude, there are literally hundreds of tutorials on how to do this: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

If your change can be done using only xml, you can create your own row view xml and pass it to your ArrayAdapter. In other cases you should implement your own ListAdapter. It has getView method where you can do everything you mentioned. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html , http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

To change colours you simpley add the colour code (Google HTML colour codes) in the xml

eg:
for a Button:

```
<Button
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

Heres a list
http://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom listview by designing the layout accordingly in an xml file . Then set the Adapter which extends BaseAdapter or listAdapter. In the getview method inflate that xml layout and make changes you want.
For example,

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ViewHolder vh;
            if(convertView == null) {
                vh = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                //put your code here
                convertView.setTag(vh);
            }else {
                vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }




            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I code the xml layout in order to make the changes I stated?